# How to fix "Expecting pointer type" and "symbol already different kind" in macros

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried adding the prefix @@ in the macros as well declaring local @@label in the macros, it didn't work.

I've also checked this site [link](https://www.shsu.edu/~csc_tjm/fall2000/cs272/ch8.html)
as well that was mentioned in the previous problems... It didn't work.

```
.286
.model small
.stack 100h

writeString macro string, length, x, y, color
    mov ah, 13h
    mov al, 0
    mov bh, 0
    mov bl, color
    lea bp, string
    mov cx, length
    mov dl, x
    mov dh, y
    int 10h
endm

draw_box_outline macro x_fin,y_fin,x_ini,y_ini

    local col_draw,row_draw,row_rev,col_rev

    mov cx,x_ini
    mov dx,y_ini
    mov ah,0ch
    mov al,1111b
    int 10h

    col_draw:
    inc cx
    int 10h
    cmp cx,x_fin
    jb col_draw    

    row_draw:
    inc dx
    int 10h
    cmp dx,y_fin
    jb row_draw

    row_rev:
    dec cx
    int 10h
    cmp cx,x_ini
    ja row_rev

    col_rev:
    dec dx
    int 10h
    cmp dx,y_ini
    ja col_rev
endm

.data
msg db "Select Number of Player/s$"
msg1 db "1$"

;box parameters
b1_col_ini equ 50
b1_row_ini equ 110
b1_col_fin equ 90
b1_row_fin equ 150

b2_col_ini equ 130
b2_row_ini equ 110
b2_col_fin equ 170
b2_row_fin equ 150

b3_col_ini equ 210
b3_row_ini equ 110
b3_col_fin equ 250
b3_row_fin equ 150

.code
org 100h
main proc far
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax

    mov ah,0h
    mov al,13h
    mov bh,0
    int 10h

    writeString msg,25,7,10,1111b

    draw_box_outline b1_col_fin,b1_row_fin,b1_col_ini,b1_row_ini
    draw_box_outline b2_col_fin,b2_row_fin,b2_col_ini,b2_row_ini
    draw_box_outline b3_col_fin,b3_row_fin,b3_col_ini,b3_row_ini

    writeString msg,25,7,10,1111b
    ;implement cursor press and detection
    ;implement cursor hide

    mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h
main endp
end main
```

In DOSBox I keep getting the error "expected pointer type" and "symbol already of different kind" but in emu8086, there wasn't any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LOCAL` directive must be at the very beginning of the macro. The blank line between the macro declaration and the LOCAL line is already too much. It should look like this:

```
draw_box_outline macro x_fin,y_fin,x_ini,y_ini
local col_draw,row_draw,row_rev,col_rev
```

Also, take a look here: [TASM; LOCAL and LOCALS directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896060/tasm-local-and-locals-directives).

Comment: Oh, I didn’t know about that. I’ve read that thread before but I’m not quite sure what he meant. Though, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was using the same name for segment and a variable:

```
tekrar segment
.
.
.
loopne tekrar
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).